# Windows 8. 1 update holds on 78%?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update

I have gone through different forums. But few stated that antivirus is preventing while upgrading it. But I just disabled the protection than tried again.  But it stops on the same level. No improvements. I tried it more than 5 times.

Mine Windows 8 64 bit os.

Comment: You should uninstall the anti-virus protection or verify at the very least the version your using supports Windows 8.1

Comment: I have done the verification.  It's supported for the updates.  And I tried it more than 5 times.

Comment: I still say uninstall the software, perform the upgrade, then just install it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8.1 Upgrade progress bar is next to useless. It may be that the last 22% can take a *long* while, though progress is *nil*.

1. Follow [Microsoft's procedure for removing old update attempt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80070003#1TC=windows-7) (this is for Windows 7 but should apply to 8.1 also).
2. Follow these [further directions](https://www.404techsupport.com/2013/01/how-to-delete-cached-windows-updates-in-windows-78/) and/or these [tips on removing a partial update](http://www.howtogeek.com/206271/how-to-roll-back-or-uninstall-a-problematic-windows-update/).
3. Try running the update again, and be patient... it may take up to an hour for some PC's and updates.